# In QGIS, the image in my print manager cannot be saved and only save one layer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I try to save an image I made from my print manager in QGIS to my computer, it only seems to save part of it. Eg one layer is saved but another layer from the image isnt. How can this be solved??

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Which version of QGIS are you using? Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: What page size and resolution are you using.  It could be that your PC spec is not up to the task if these are large (that could be a problem with your machine and not QGIS) - if so try lowering the output resolution and/or page size.

Comment: The print composer does not automatically update maps. It could be that you made changes to the map in the main project window, and the changes weren't visible in the print composer. It's a good idea to manually refresh the print composer before exporting, to make sure that the export is as expected.